# WPF ComboBox with multiple ItemsPresenter

Tags: wpf, combobox, itemspresenter

I need to create a custom ComboBox with 2 ItemsPresenter but I don't know how to set the ItemsPresenter where to add and remove items.

I have tried to get the ItemsPresenter:

```
ItemsPresenter itemsPresenter = (ItemsPresenter)comboBoxAlbum.FindName("ItemsPresenterAlbum");
```

but I don't know how to get the Items collection.

This is how I have modified the Popup part:

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
    <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
        <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
            <Grid Background="White">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#FF929CA4">
                    <ScrollViewer Background="#FF929CA4">
                        <Grid x:Name="ToolBar" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="#FF929CA4">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <StackPanel x:Name="btnStretchNone" MouseUp="btnStretch_MouseUp" Grid.Column="0" Background="{Binding BtnStretchNone}" Style="{DynamicResource StakPanelEffect}">
                                <Image Width="32" Height="32" Margin="5" Source="Resources/StretchNone.png"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="btnStretchFill" MouseUp="btnStretch_MouseUp" Grid.Column="1" Background="{Binding BtnStretchFill}" Style="{DynamicResource StakPanelEffect}">
                                <Image Width="32" Height="32" Margin="5" Source="Resources/StretchFill.png"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="btnStretchUniform" MouseUp="btnStretch_MouseUp" Grid.Column="2" Background="{Binding BtnStretchUniform}" Style="{DynamicResource StakPanelEffect}">
                                <Image Width="32" Height="32" Margin="5" Source="Resources/StretchUniform.png"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="btnStretchUniformFill" MouseUp="btnStretch_MouseUp" Grid.Column="3" Background="{Binding BtnStretchUniformFill}" Style="{DynamicResource StakPanelEffect}">
                                <Image Width="32" Height="32" Margin="5" Source="Resources/StretchUniformFill.png"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="btnSettings" MouseUp="btnSettings_MouseUp" Grid.Column="4" Background="{Binding BtnStretchFrame}" Style="{DynamicResource StakPanelEffect}" IsEnabled="False">
                                <Image Width="32" Height="32" Margin="5" Source="Resources/SettingsB.png"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <TabControl Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ConverterParameter=-42, Converter={StaticResource AdditionConverter}, ElementName=DropDownBorder}">
                        <TabItem Header="Albums">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewerAlbum">
                                <Grid x:Name="gridAlbum" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas x:Name="canvasAlbum" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRectAlbum" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ConverterParameter=-72, Converter={StaticResource AdditionConverter}, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ConverterParameter=-8, Converter={StaticResource AdditionConverter}, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenterAlbum" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem Header="Slides">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewerSlide">
                                <Grid x:Name="gridSlide" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas x:Name="canvasSlide" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRectSlide" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ConverterParameter=-72, Converter={StaticResource AdditionConverter}, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ConverterParameter=-8, Converter={StaticResource AdditionConverter}, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenterSlide" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </TabItem>
                    </TabControl>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
</Popup>
```

There are 2 ItemsPresenter (ItemsPresenterAlbum, ItemsPresenterSlide). How can I add items to a specific ItemsPresenter? Using the Items.Add() it add only to the second ItemsPresenter.

Comment: Why do you believe that you need two ItemsPresenters?

Comment: Have you seen the Xaml? Can you suggest a different way to achieve this with a single ItemsPresenter?

Comment: I would first look at using an ItemsControl for at least one of those. If you want to get any child of the ControlTemplate, override OnApplyTemplate() in your combobox subclass and call `Template.FindName("ItemsPresenterSlide", this) as ItemsPresenter;`. Looks like you haven't written a subclass, but if I were going to try to make this work, I'd be writing a subclass.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have write already the override OnApplyTemplate() for the "buttons" but I though there is a way to use the ItemsPresenter instead to add ItemsControl so that I can use the Add() method just selecting the ItemsPresenter needed.

Comment: ItemsPresenter, like ContentPresenter is meant to be treated as magic, or near-magic. You don't call Add() on it. I would seriously look at adding an ItemsControl for one of them, with `ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"`.

Comment: Yes this is the point, I can't call Add() on ItemsPresenter but it show the Items added to the ComboBox with Add() method. Looking at ComboBox and ItemsPresenter source code I though it could be possible to select the Panel used by ComboBox to add items, but I was not able to understand how it work.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I follow your suggestion and added a ListBox for the second Tab since I need to rise the event for SelectionChanged. The problem now is how can I add a public property to my custom ComboBox to bind the Items of the ListBox?

Comment: `ItemsPresenter` will add the `Panel` internally by applying the `ItemsPanelTemplate`. This will add a `Panel` to the visual tree. The `Panel` then uses the `ItemContainerGenerator` to create the visual items and also handles their layout. You cannot add items to an `ItemsPresenter` but specify its template by setting the parents `ItemsPanelTemplate` e.g. `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel`. As recommended by Ed Plunkett you should use an `ItemsControl`.

Comment: @BionicCode Thanks for your explanation, now is much more clear how it work!

Comment: Yes, this is the way I have used to bind some properties for the "buttons" but for the ListBox I would like to have a public property for my control to use as myCustomComboBox.SlideList.Add("Test")

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you right, but if you add a Dependency Property of type e.g., `ObservableCollection` named _"SideList"_ to your `myCustomComboBox` control you can call `myCustomComboBox.SideList.Add("Test")` to add items. The `ListBox` should bind to this collection in order to display those items.

Comment: Yes! this is what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @BionicCode I'm not sure how to use ObservableCollection but I have tried with an ItemCollection, the problem is that I get a null reference exception when I try to add the item.

Comment: Given that the property is named _SideList_, you have to initialize it. You can do this either from the constructor of your control or by specifying a default value for the Dependency Property. `ItemCollection` is a `CollectionView` and doesn't provide a public constructor. I recommend to use a `ObservableCollection` since adding items to it will automatically update the bound `ListBox`: The Dependency Property should look like this:

Comment: `public static readonly DependencyProperty SideListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "SideList",
      typeof(ObservableCollection<string>),
      typeof(MyCustomComboBox),
      new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<string>()));

    public ObservableCollection<string> SideList
    {
      get => (ObservableCollection<string>) GetValue(MyCustomComboBox.SideListProperty);
      set => SetValue(MyCustomComboBox.SideListProperty, value);
    }`. The property is initialized by specifying a default value for the `PropertyMetadata` parameter and therefore ready to use.

Comment: NullReferenceException  is thrown when an object is not initialized (e.g., by using the `new` key word).

Comment: @BionicCode Thanks! It work now! new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<string>()) This is the part I missed. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user2272143 Careful with providing a new instance of a refrence type as the default value of a dependency property: Unless the value is replaced, every instance of your class will share the same observable collection with every other. That's not what you're looking for. Usually you can initialize such a property with a new collection in your class's constructor, which will get each instance its own collection.